# How to limit UIImagePickerController to only picking portrait mode (depth effect) photos?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm building an app that deals with images taken in Portrait Mode (Depth Effect). I need to present `UIImagePickerController` to only display photos that have depth effect.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not possible** with the public methods of `UIImagePickerController`. Use a custom image picker for this.

For checking if a specific `PHAsset` has a depth effect, check whether its `mediaSubtypes` property is equal to `.photoDepthEffect`:

```
if asset.mediaSubtypes == .photoDepthEffect {
    //live photo          
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up writing a custom collection view controller that accesses photo library using `[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumDepthEffect options:nil]` method.

Comment: Note that it is probably better to use `PHFetchOptions` with a predicate of `(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0` where `%d` is the raw value of the required media subtype, than to fetch everything and manually remove those with the wrong subtype.

Comment: @Ash I agree with that, yes.